# How to pass char * from char** to const char *

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int len = 10;
char * strNumber1 = new char[2*len+1];
char * strNumber2 = new char[2*len+1];
int cmp(const char *str1,const char *str2){
    strcpy(strNumber1,*(const char**)str1);
    strcat(strNumber1,*(const char**)str2);

    strcpy(strNumber2,*(const char**)str2);
    strcat(strNumber2,*(const char**)str1);

    return strcmp(strNumber1,strNumber2);
}
string PrintMinNumber(vector<int> numbers) {
    int length = numbers.size();

    char **numStr = new char*[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        sprintf(numStr[i],"%d",numbers[i]);
    }

    sort((char*) numStr[0],(char*)numStr[length],cmp);
    // I don't know how to pass the char* from char** numStr;
    string ans = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        ans += numStr[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[3] = {3,32,321};
    vector<int> numbers(a,a+3);
    cout<<PrintMinNumber(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

The above is my code which is used to solve the problem, which is how to get the minimum number from such as 3,321,32. We may get the result is 321323. So I need to sort the string, but I don't know how to pass `char *` from `char**` to `const char*`. Can you explain what I need to do?

Comment: Don't spam tags. C is not C++ is not C! Then read [ask]. What you ask for is definitively wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This explanation for improvement:

If you initialize  : `char **numStr = new char*[10];`
You actually already have 10 arrays of type char *.

You can imagine like this :
numStr = [addressOfChar-0, addressOfChar-1, ..., addressOfChar-9];
Then for the sort function, you can directly fill the begin-index and end-index parameters of Y, as below:
`sort(numStr,numStr + length,cmp);`

For the parameters of strcpy and strcat in function cmp (`int cmp(const char *str1,const char *str2)`), you do not need to cast to `(const char **)`. Because str1 and str2 are elements of numStr or addressOfChar-N.

For strcmp you have to Compare smaller than 0, because If return -1 the result is true, You can try the code below:
`bool check = (-1? True: false);`

You do not forget to `delete` all the variables that use Memory heap (`new`), because it can cause leak memory.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int len = 10;
char * strNumber1 = new char[2*len+1];
char * strNumber2 = new char[2*len+1];
int cmp(const char *str1,const char *str2){
    strcpy(strNumber1,str1);
    strcat(strNumber1,str2);

    strcpy(strNumber2,str2);
    strcat(strNumber2,str1);
    return strcmp(strNumber1, strNumber2) < 0;
}
string PrintMinNumber(vector<int> numbers) {
    int length = numbers.size();
    char **numStr = new char*[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (numbers[i] == 0)
        {
            numStr[i] = new char[2];
        }
        else
        {
            numStr[i] = new char[log(numbers[i]) + 2];
        }

        sprintf(numStr[i],"%d",numbers[i]);
    }

    sort(numStr,numStr + length,cmp);
    string ans = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        ans += numStr[i];
        delete[] numStr[i];
    }
    delete[] numStr;
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 321,3,32 };
    vector<int> numbers(a,end(a));
    cout<<PrintMinNumber(numbers);
    delete[] strNumber1;
    delete[] strNumber2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I am very sorry, I can't vote.